# Enviar um CANVAS por email via PHPMailer

Tags: php, jquery, phpmailer

Estou criando um simulador com carrinho, onde quando o cliente adiciona o produto simulado no carrinho tem que enviar o print gerado junto com o email para o comercial.

Porem não consigo pensar numa forma de que a imagem gerada (CANVAS ou IMG) seja enviada juntamente no email via PHP.

Comment: Adicione mais informações, por favor, como você envia o e-mail, código, ...

Comment: Ainda não criei o codigo para enviar o email, mas o problema esta no fato que utilizo o rasterizeHTML para gerar um canvas a partir de um html, logo depois gero um link para usar na tag IMG, preciso enviar essa img por email como anexo